# Нужно написать форму с помощью JS и HTML для приложения, но я не знаю как, нужен совет

Tags: javascript, python, html5

Объясняю - попросил у учителя задание, и вот что он дал: "Необходимо разработать web-приложение - Список дел. Функционал простой: добавить, удалить, отметить выполненным. Визуальная часть в произвольной форме. Используемые технологии. Бэкенд Python Django, в качестве хранилища можно использовать  любую БД или хранить в оперативной памяти для упрощения, на фронтенде использовать html + javascript без дополнительных каркасов приложений (фреймворков)." - у меня есть 2 недели максимум, помогите мне, пожалуйста :3
Вообщем я поискал инфу про то как создавать такие формы, но ничего нужного не нашёл( Можете сказать, что использовать в JS, да и вообще - как это делать? Заранее спасибо!

PS.
Я немного знаю HTML, но с JS не работал никогда, тем более никогда не делал визуальщину на них...

Comment: Это за один день пишется даже без JS (чисто на Django). Перевожу на русский, что вас попросили сделать: *напишите на Django интерфейс к питоновскому классу `list`*.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Generic_views Тут более чем достаточно информации. Думаю, если действительно хотите сделать, за сегодняшний вечер управитесь.